# Android Studio cannot resolve symbols

Tags: java, android, symbols, drawable, resolve

At first i had to rename the .png file names because they were not acceptable. Now that i have renamed them and change the name on the code i still get an error that my drawable 'd6' etc cannot be found. I have tried restarting my application and look for the issue but, I cannot seem to find the problem.

In case this is relevant:

```
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/diceContainer">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvHelp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/back"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Touch on the screen to start rolling."
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:id="@+id/die1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/d6" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:id="@+id/die2"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/d6" />


    </LinearLayout>




</LinearLayout>
```

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int delayTime =20;
    int rollAnimations = 40;
    int[] diceImages = new int[] {R.drawable.d1,R.drawable.d2,R.drawable.d3,R.drawable.d4,R.drawable.d5,R.drawable.d6};
    Random random = new Random();
    TextView tvHelp;
    ImageView die1;
    ImageView die2;
    LinearLayout diceContainer;
    MediaPlayer mp;
```

These are also some screenshots below :

[image]

[image]

I tried renaming the files and restarting android studio.

Comment: Clean and rebuild your project: Sometimes, changes in resource files may not take effect immediately. Try cleaning your project and then rebuilding it to ensure that the updated drawable resources are properly compiled and included in the build